Can I merge textures in Blender?
I've created diffuse and roughness textures in my shader, but I want to merge this textures into one, because as I know, diffuse requires RGB channels and roughness is just a channel with values from 0 to 1 (or 255, don't remember). So, I think I can put this values into alpha channel. Can I do this in Blender?
I don't want to use photoshop or GIMP for this, I'm looking for built-in solution or simple add-on.
I've seen this question, but can't understand the concept of baking - when I'm trying to bake like this:

I'm getting empty image. I can enable direct and indirect lighting, but am I need it? I don't want to bake light - I just need colors.
Update: According to @unwave answer, I decided to try to use compositor, but I don't have any experience with it. For now I created this:

Is it correct? What should I do next?

For that, you use foreach_get and foreach_set on bpy.types.Image.pixels or a compositor setup, not baking. You can only bake into the RGB channels.
To save the composed image, you can use the Viewer Node, the result image would be available as Viewer Node. Or File Output Node to save to a file directly.


Thank you! Can you provide more information about compositing method? I've edited my question and added more details.

@Сергей I have added the info about the node usage.
